# Hair particle problem after rendering

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, particles, hair

Good day guys.
I want to ask why my hair particle kind of messed up when I render it?
I provided the blender file below.
Thank you guys!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Calvin reporting.

I figured it out why.
Under Children > Interpolated.
The Display Amount and Render Amount must be of the same value.
:)

[image]